# How to write a separate line for a text file

Tags: java, android

So when I write to my text file using `FileOutputSstream` I have used both

```
fos.write(("0"+"\n").getBytes());
```

and

```
fos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
```

and neither of them work... they still print on the same line...

Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you "see" that "they still print on the same line"?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are writing it correctly, and then trying to look at it with a program that thinks that newlines look like `\r\n` instead of simply `\n`

Comment: I see it by hooking my phone up onto my computer and finding the file and it is all on the same line... and tucuxi can u elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a PrintStream

System.out is a PrintStream for example.

You say you have a FileOutputStream. Then,

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(f);
ps.print("line1");
ps.println(); //this writes your new line
ps.print("line2");
ps.close();
```

also you can use;

```
BufferedWriter fos = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename)));
      fos.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
      fos.newLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I figured it out... for some reason when I tried every example here the only thing that worked was     ps.print("one\r\n");
Its really strange since I have know idea why it works but it does...

Comment: "one" doesnt mean anything... i was just putting it there "\r\n" is what works its crazy!

Comment: "\r\n" is 0x0d,0x0a -- which means that, wherever you read those files, you were expecting windows newlines, instead of the unixy ones you were writing.

Answer (score 1):

Newlines are different in each platform. For unix systems (MacOS X, Linux, ... and Android, since it uses a modified linux kernel), the line-separator is `0x0A`; for MS Windows, it its two bytes long: `0x0D,0x0A`; for old-school MacOS, it is `0x0D`.

This means that an Android-newline written by Android will be invisible when opened by a particularly stupid Windows program such as Notepad.exe. A wiser program (such as a programming editor or an IDE) will display it without trouble.

Comment: Also note that certain protocols expect line-separators to be `0x0d,0x0a` style - for instance, HTTP

Comment: That's not my problem... when i put things in and when i read line by line into a string array i only get one value... do you have any idea how to fix this problem? because i don't think its just because of notepad...

Comment: What bytes get written in the file? Are you reading them back in with Java under Windows, where newlines may default to 0x0D,0x0A? Please update your question with a hex dump of the relevant bits of your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use println method

```
PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("outputPath"));
for(String line:lines)
    ps.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public  byte[] newLine() {
    byte[] temp = new byte[2];
    temp[0] = 13;
    temp[1] = 10;
    return temp;
}
```

Just write this to your FileOuputStream.
Like this:

```
    FileOutputStream.write(newLine());
```

This will simply write the bytes: 13 and 10.

Comment: also known as a "windows newline"

Answer (score -1):

You have to append the line seperator / break like this.

Try

```
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    fos.append(seperator);
```